# NameError: name 'tokenize_and_split_data' is not defined in Python code

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, training-data, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers

I want to divide the data into `train_dataset` and `test_dataset` variables. The function `tokenize_and_split_data` did not work and `utilities` library did not define. I am working on Python google colab.

```
import datasets
import tempfile
import logging
import random
import config
import os
import yaml
import time
import torch
import transformers
import pandas as pd
import jsonlines

#from utilities import *
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM
from transformers import TrainingArguments
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
global_config = None

model_name = "EleutherAI/pythia-70m"

training_config = {
    "model": {
        "pretrained_name": model_name,
        "max_length" : 2048
    },
    "datasets": {
        "use_hf": use_hf,
        "path": dataset_path
    },
    "verbose": True
}

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
train_dataset, test_dataset = tokenize_and_split_data(training_config, tokenizer)

print(train_dataset)
print(test_dataset)
```

---

Above, is the code, I cannot install `utilities` library, and this function `tokenize_and_split_data` did not defined. Can you help me please.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the collab from Lamini on finetuning, there is a python file utilities.py that contains this method. Just recreate this file or copy paste all the methods in a cell.

```bash
$ ls
05_Training_lab_student.ipynb  lamini_docs.jsonl    utilities.py
__pycache__                    lamini_docs_3_steps

$ cat utilities.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Download "utilities.py" from [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Artificial-Intelligence-with-Python/tree/master/Chapter%2002/code) and paste it in your python folder which named "...\Lib\site-packages", you can find this path by 'cmd' command "python -v".

Comment: The library imported successfully, but this function tokenize_and_split_data still do not work